# Is it possible to suspend all Windows Defender tasks when my program runs, and resume when it's done?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-10, suspend

I have a performance-sensitive program that I would like to run as stably as possible, thus I'm wanting to disable/suspend MsMpEng.exe, among a few others, to hopefully attain that on Windows 10 when my program starts. When the program finishes, I'd like to restore normal previous function.

I have tried directly suspending the process using resmon.exe (Resource Monitor), and it suspends... but 20-30 seconds later, the entire system just stops. I assume this is some form of self-protect... so at the very least, I'd have to suspend and resume in a timed loop.

Thoughts? Is it even worth the trouble?

EDIT: Gave it some thought and some test cases, and just adjusting process priority isn't quite enough, but it's better than nothing. I'll just recommend people disable their virus protection if they encounter slow downs unless anyone else has any suggestions.

Comment: and then what is the point in defender if everyone can suspend/dissable it ?

Comment: @RbMm you have a good point, but surely there's a way to disable background virus scanning which always seems to occur when I'm doing the most important tasks without having to instruct the users of my software to disable virus protection. Like a `windefend.exe /pause` of sorts.

Comment: if your code have admin privilege you of course can stop/disable *windefend* service and related. however you need for this *NT SERVICE\WinDefend* or *NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller* sids in self token (or first change *DACL* for *windefend*) not sure that you can open *MsMpEng.exe* process for get it token. but you can run *TrustedInstaller* service, open *TrustedInstaller.exe* and impersonate with it token. under such token you can do any with *windefend* . exist and another ways but need amdministrator access anyway

Comment: defender is a protected process, so trying to suspend threads will fail.Exclude your exe from scan

Comment: Creating a virus?

Comment: The documented way is to set process/thread priorities with SetThreadPriority and SetPriorityClass.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis While I see the potential for virus-esque, it's much more mundane. Making a utility to improve video game performance on systems where resources are limited for my own personal use. I'll try setting the priority class and see where that takes me. Thanks!

Comment: @Jim there are there very gpu-intensive games that do not have a problem with antivirus (besides, AV is pretty much useless anyway) so I guess you don't need anything extraordinary.